# html5 canvas image inside trasparent

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to put an image inside a frame, i would like to adapt the image over the trasparent area of the frame.

I've tryed to do this way: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ymzwdaw9/

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var imageURLs=[];  
    imageURLs.push("http://i.imgur.com/LKx3Yel.png");
    imageURLs.push("http://i.imgur.com/cXOrsmT.jpg");

    var imgs=[];
    var imagesOK=0;
    loadAllImages(start);

    function loadAllImages(callback){
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            imgs.push(img);
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }      
    }

    function start(){


        ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0);

    }

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=884 height=1171></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

but there are 2 problems:

1. the image is under the frame borders
2. the image is not big enough (i guess its because should be cropped and stretched?)

i know i could specify the position of the image via coordinates, but the problem is the user can pick different kinds of frames, so the best solution would be "replace" the trasparent area with the image.

P.S. i'm trying with canvas, but other solutions are welcome

Comment: Is this what your looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/sev9m79z/ 
It stretches to the inner image size.

Comment: fiddle is not working, i have fixed it (http://jsfiddle.net/sev9m79z/1/) the problem is it should be for mobile, so need to be responsive... thats why i tryed with canvas

Comment: Yh sorry forgot to save here is an update with responsive image: http://jsfiddle.net/4qr39jLo/